# Comparing datetime in gridview eval

Tags: asp.net, datetime, gridview, eval, bind

I have a label in gridview where I display the message sent dateTime depending on whether the message was sent today or earlier.If the message was sent today, it should display the time and if it was sent earlier it displays the date (dd-MM-yyyy). SentDateTime is the column which gives out the required dateTime.

I have tried the below :

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMsgTime" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SentDateTime","{0:dd-MM-yyyy}").Equals(DateTime.Now,"{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")? Eval("SentDateTime","{0:HH:mm}"):Eval("SentDateTime","{0:dd-MM-yyyy}") %>' style="color: #FFFFFF"></asp:Label>
```

but throws the exception

Member 'object.Equals(object, object)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do this on the server row data bound event?

Comment: I don't want to use an event here for some reason so want to follow the above method

Comment: Have you tried basic comparision **==** instead of **equals**.

Comment: Yeah missed on the ToString here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you forgot to call `ToString` on the `DateTime.Now`:

```
.Equals(DateTime.Now.ToString("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}"))
```

However this all is very complicated. There is no need to compare strings when dates can be compared directly:

```
<%# (DateTime)Eval("SentDateTime") == DateTime.Now ? ...
```

And even this looks too much for a markup. Consider moving this logic to code behind function:

```
protected string GetDateValue(DateTime sentDateTime)
{
    if (sentDateTime == DateTime.Now)
    {
        return sentDateTime.ToString("HH:mm");
    }
    else
    {
        return sentDateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
<%# GetDateValue((DateTime)Eval("SentDateTime")) %>
```

Comment: Although I am pretty convinced that I have to use code-behind to keep the codes clean, are there any other benefits of using code-behind? The above worked like a charm btw

Comment: @RelatedRhymes, no, no other benefits in general. Readability is the only one it seems, although a big one. However in this particular case you will enjoy a tiny bit of performance increase, because of one evaluation of `Eval` (instead of 4 times you had originally). I'd be surprised if you notice that though